# In which table add isDefault column?

Tags: sql, database-design, boolean

I have two tables, suppose Customers and their Contacts. Each customer can have one contact which is default. Which solution is better add boolean isDefault column to the Contacts table with appropriate trigger or add defaultContactId to the Customers table? Please substantiate your answer.

Comment: a boolean isDefault in Contact presumably means there will only ever be the same single default contact for everyone ...

Answer (score 1):

Keeping a bidirectional relationship between Customer and Contacts by keeping a foreign key to the Customer i.e. customerId in Contacts table and keeping a defaultContactId in the Customer table is not a good idea. This is because this relationship is not bi-directional in relational terms.

The relationship between the entities, as described, is that one Customer can have many Contacts i.e. a One-To-Many relationship between Customer and Contacts, which would need a CustomerId foreign key in Contacts table. Now, one of the contacts is the default contact. That is a property/attribute of the Contact that it is default. It is not a property of the Customer. So, isDefaultContact should be a column in Contacts table.

Comment: The "defaultness" of the contact is arguably also a property of the customer, which becomes apparent when you have more levels in the hierarchy and have to express a default per customer and a default per "customer group", for example. I don't think it is as clear cut. I feel I should also mention that there is no concept of directionality in the relationship between database tables, even taking into account which table has the foreign key. A relationship is just a relationship.

Answer (score 0):

If you added a boolean `isDefault` column to the `Contacts` table, you will also need another column `CustomerId` to the contacts table too.

So, it will better to use only one foreign key `DefaultContactId` which should be nullable to the customers table.

---

**Update**:

Since you already have a foreign key `CustomerId`, then adding a boolean `isDefault` column to the Contacts table will be enough and no need to another foreign key, because you can find who is this customer using the foreign key reference `CustomerId`.

Comment: anyway I have customerId foreighn key because I need relation between customers and contacts and defaultContactId foreign key doesnt't provide that relation.

Comment: @Vahan - Then, no need for another foreign key and add a boolean `isDefault` column, see my updated.

Comment: @ Mahmoud Gamal , if I use defaultContactId foreign key than there is no need to have isDefault and vice versa. This 2 is alternative solutions.

Comment: @Vahan - Yes, this true, but you don't have to use a foreign key if you use `isdefault`

Comment: @ Mahmoud Gamal , but I have to use trigger or smth like that when updating isDefault value, because only one can be default

Comment: @vahan Triggers never guarantee relational integrity. They can only see committed data.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is no single answer to this which will satisfy everyone, and the best approach may depend on the application

You can look at it both ways: "Is this contact the default for the customer?", and think of "default" as an attribute of the contact, or "For this customer, which contact is the default?" in which case it is an attribute of the customer.

The uniqueness of the default in respect of the customer is better supported by using a "default contact id" attribute on the customer table, as it is a simple matter of foreign keys. You can enforce uniqueness of the "is default" field in the contact table, but it can involve some slightly non-standard tricks.

The best choice may depend on the systems that are interfacing with the data. I find that Ruby on Rails works well with a default contact id on the customer table -- others might vary, and I doubt that there is a definitive answer.