# EF create additional foreign key column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In my app, users can write posts. What's more, every user can have 0 or 1 favourite post. I wanted to have my database schema like this:

dbo.users

```
+----+--------+-----------------+
| Id | Name   | FavouritePostId |
+----+--------+-----------------+
| 1  | Adam   | 1               |
| 2  | Daniel | 2               |
| 3  | Aaron  | null            |
+----+--------+-----------------+
```

dbo.posts

```
+----+---------+--------+
| Id | Content | UserId |
+----+---------+--------+
| 1  | Hello   | 1      |
| 2  | World   | 1      |
| 3  | foo     | 2      |
+----+---------+--------+
```

which means:

- Adam is creator of posts `1,2`, and his favourite post is `post.id = 1`
- Daniel is creator of post `3`, and his favourite post is `post.id = 2`.
- Aaron didn't added any post and marked as favourite

I wanted to create that with Entity Framework code first approach.
These are my entities:

```cs
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("FavouritePost")]
    public int? FavouritePostId { get; set; }
    public Post FavouritePost { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

but I ended up with that table:

dbo.posts

```
+----+---------+--------+---------+
| Id | Content | UserId | User_Id |  
+----+---------+--------+---------+
```

How can I get rid of that additional `User_Id` column?

Comment: Personally I think you have this backwards: a Post being the Favourite is related to the Post, not the User, so `Post` needs a `IsFavourite` property, rather than a `FavouritePost` on `User`.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33101398/in-which-table-add-isdefault-column. To enforce only one Favourite, you can create a filtered unique index `Post (UserId) WHERE (IsFavourite = 1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serge's answer essentially covers the issue. To expand a bit on that, part of the issue is that you are using "Id" as the PK for User. The issue here is that when EF goes to associate the Post to a User, the "Id" PK will natively become "User_Id" for the FK name. The solution is either to give EF a hint/configuration what is should use as the FK (InverseProperty or explicit mapping), or using "UserId" as the PK in User should have it pair up automatically with the FK property in Post.

For EF6, if you do want to maintain "Id" as the PK in User, the configuration option (through either `OnModelCreating()`, or using an `EntityTypeConfiguration`) would be:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
    .HasOne(p => p.User)
    .WithMany(u => u.Posts)
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.UserId);
```

I agree that it's generally not wise to have Posts and FavoritePost as navigation properties. There is no way to constrain data integrity that FavoritePostId will point to a Post that actually is associated with that user. (A FavoritePost reference on User #1 can legally point to a Post that has a UserId of 2.)  Alternatives would be to use something like an "IsFavorite" flag, however that has a similar issue that there is no constraint that only 1 post is marked as a favorite (if any). Another alternative would be to give Posts a Rank as a unique constraint /w the UserId. This way your business logic can determine a favorite being the lowest or highest rank post.

Answer (score 0):

you have to fix some relations

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(Post.User))]
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    
   
    public int? FavouritePostId { get; set; }
     [ForeignKey("FavouritePostId")]
   [InverseProperty("Users")]
    public virtual Post FavouritePost { get; set; }
}
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    [InverseProperty("Posts")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    
    [InverseProperty(nameof(User.FavouritePost))]
     public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

}
```

but I would  just add

```
public bool IsFavorite {get; set;}
```

to Post class

Comment: 2 ways of using `InverseProperty` is necessary? I mean you are passing parameter as a `string`, or `nameof`

Comment: @dafie You can use the  way you like. I am personally prefer nameof, but if you have the same name of property as the name of class  it sometimes overlaps and compiler gives errror. So I will have to use a string.